# Predicative logic implication, is it true?

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm struggling to find a counterexample for this expression...

$\left(\forall x P(x) \longrightarrow \forall x Q(X)\right) \overset{is\ this \ true??}{\longrightarrow} \forall x (P(x) \longrightarrow Q(x)) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the universe be the set of integers and say

- $P(x)$ means "$x$ is even";
- $Q(x)$ means "$x$ is odd".

Then
$$\forall x P(x) \longrightarrow \forall x Q(x)$$
is true, but
$$\forall x (P(x) \longrightarrow Q(x))$$
is false.

Comment: So much thanks!